# Checking for an "end of line" in a C-string

Tags: c

I want to get as an input from the user a maximum length of 30 chars string and check whether it contains an end of line.

This is what I tried to write so far:

```
int main(void) {
int i;
char* command = (char*)calloc(31, sizeof(char));
while (0 < 1) {
    scanf("%s", command);
    for (i = 0; i <= strlen(command); ++i) {
        if (command[i] == '\n')
            printf("here");
    }
    if (strcmp(command, "quit") == 0)
        break;
}
```

The idea is to check whether the command given by the user as input is "legal" - that is of length < 31.
when i run this code, it never prints "here" regardless of the length of input.

Comment: Note that your use of the `%s` format specifier here is dangerous. If the user inputs more than 30 characters, `scanf()` will write to memory beyond what is allocated by `calloc()`.

Comment: If you are set on using `scanf`, you should specify the size of the buffer to `scanf` explicitly: instead of `"%s"`, pass `"%30s"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because `scanf()` doesn't include the linefeed, it considers it whitespace and uses whitespace to separate the values it converts. Just use `strlen()`'s return value.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but still, how would I know if it contains this char or not? Do you mean using the strlen just for knowing if it contains more or less than 30 characters? but still I need to check for a specific commands, all of them have length less than 30. if I'll write down  "nnnnnnnnnnn... (*100)", as far I understand, since I allowed the program to allocate only 30-size it would cut it to "nnnn...*(30)" and than when I would check for its length it would still give me that it is <= 30, Isn't it? and than the whole point is gone..

Comment: and wtill I can't allocate more than length of 30, because I can't predict the length of the input, on the other hand as Jonathan said,  If the user inputs more than 30 characters, scanf() will write to memory beyond what is allocated by calloc(). How should I handle this problem?

Comment: @Numerator He is saying that it will never contain a newline character since `scanf()` reads until whitespace (including a newline character) and then returns what is has read minus the newline.  This means what you have left already IS what was entered before the newline.

Answer (score 5):

`scanf` does not include the terminating `'\n'`, but [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/) does:

> A newline character makes fgets stop reading, but it is considered a valid character and therefore it is included in the string copied to str.

Simply change your `scanf` line to this:

```
fgets(command, 31, stdin);
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning f :)

Answer (score 1):

use fgets (for more information man fgets) the stream you are reading from is stdin.

It would look something like this:

```
fgets(command, 31, stdin);
```

At the end of the string (if there are no errors) you can look for '\0'. It will be appended to the end of the string (that is why I used 31 instead of 30 for the size).

Also, you can use fgets to read from any stream (ie. file, error ect..) I would suggest learning how it works because it is a little bit more flexable than scanf.

Hope that helps.